# full-screen image browser called from GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a GridView activity consisting of a single GridView that displays upto 100 image thumbnails from an sdcard location. I am creating another activity which is called when any one of the thumbnail in the grid is touched. This other activity should display the selected image in full-screen (can do this by passing the image uri to new activity). However, I would like to be able to swipe left/right from the full-screen view of the selected image to go to the next one instead of going back to the gridview activity and selecting another image for full-screen display.

How can I achieve this image browser activity that pulls images from the sdcard location for full-screen browsing using swipe gesture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a ViewFlipper

```
public class ImageViewTest extends Activity {

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

    private Animation slideLeftIn;
    private Animation slideLeftOut;
    private Animation slideRightIn;
    private Animation slideRightOut;
    private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;

    String message = "Initial Message"; 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Set up viewflipper
        viewFlipper = new ViewFlipper(this);       
        ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample_1);
        ImageView i2 = new ImageView(this);
        i2.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample_2);
        viewFlipper.addView(i);
        viewFlipper.addView(i2);

        //set up animations
        slideLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_in);
        slideLeftOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_out);
        slideRightIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_in);
        slideRightOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_out);

        //put up a brownie as a starter
        setContentView(viewFlipper);

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
    }

    public class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;
                // right to left swipe
                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    Log.v(LOGID,"right to left swipe detected");
                    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideLeftIn);
                    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideLeftOut);
                    viewFlipper.showNext();
                    setContentView(viewFlipper);

                } // left to right swipe 
                else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    Log.v(LOGID,"left to right swipe detected");                    
                    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
                    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);
                    viewFlipper.showPrevious();
                    setContentView(viewFlipper);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
return true;
else
return false;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Grab the latest version of the Compatibility Package through the SDK Manager (or go [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html))
2. Install the JAR as a lib in your project
3. Utilize `ViewPager`, which is a ViewGroup that acts like an AdapterView and does all the swipe gesture management work for you

Also, [here is an example](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) from the Android Developer Blog that may get you started.

HTH