# Implement the swipe gesture on grid view

Tags: android, gridview, swipe-gesture

i want to implement the swipe gesture on **GridView** .
for example: i have 3*3 **GridView** with 9 images when i swipe my finger to the images i want to delete the images that swiped
can somebody help me if you have any idea.

Thanks

Comment: Try to use the `GestureDetector` for `GridView`'s `onTouch()`

Comment: can you please give me the example.... thanks

Comment: [Have a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7882296/940096)

Answer (score 10):

This is example, that work on me

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GestureDetectorCompat detector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        detector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener());

        GridView board = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.board);
        board.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                detector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        detector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
                               float velocityX, float velocityY) {

            float diffY = event2.getY() - event1.getY();
            float diffX = event2.getX() - event1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }        
    }

    private void onSwipeLeft() {

    }

    private void onSwipeRight() {

    }

    private void onSwipeTop() {

    }

    private void onSwipeBottom() {

    }
}
```

Comment: you deserve more upvotes. thank you for great example

Comment: can you explain what you did here please? and is it still valid for today?