# Swipe to show option layout in grid recycler view items inside View pager?

Tags: android, swipe

I want to show the option layout above grid item (here i used Recycler grid view), when the item swiped from right to left as shown in below image and close when the item is swiped from left to right.

[image]

Does any one know how to achieve please let me know your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327095/implement-the-swipe-gesture-on-grid-view

Comment: As simple you can use viewpager.